# Error al conenectar a sql server usando mysql2

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql-server, nodejs

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo de conexion a mi bd usando mysql2, sin enbargo me sale el siguiente error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 
       at Connection._handleTimeoutError (C:\Users\jairo.jimenez\Documents\GitHub\apl_distri_reports_api\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:202:17)
       at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
       at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
       errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
       code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
       syscall: 'connect',
       fatal: true
}
```

Este es mi archivo de conexión:

```
import mysql from 'mysql2'

export const ConnectionSql = mysql.createConnection({
  user: 'sa',
  password: 'pass',
  database: 'data',
  host: 'host',
  port: 1433
})
 
export const example = async (): Promise<void> => {
  ConnectionSql.query('select 1 + 1 as suma', (err: any, res: any) => {
    if (err != null) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(res)
    }
    ConnectionSql.end()
  })
}
```

El problema es solo sucede con los servidores de mi empresa por que si me trato de conectar a otras bases de datos por ejemplo de clover cloud me permite conectarme pero con ningun servidor de la empresa me establece conexión

Comment: Entonces sera que en tu empresa, o no usan el puerto 1433, o esta cerrado para el aplicativo o cadena de conexion. En el servidor de tu empresa, es posible que tengas info, de porque se deniega la misma. Puede ser que en el visor de eventos.